# Does the latest Instagram iOS app support caption in URL scheme?

Tags: html, ios, instagram, url-scheme

Formerly it was possible in iOS to use the hook `instagram://camera?caption=YourCaptionHere` (from Mobile Safari, or elsewhere) to have the Instagram app open in camera mode with a pre-filled caption.  However, that no longer seems to be the case as my previously working URL (hook) no longer populates a caption (though it does still open Instagram in camera mode).

I'm having trouble finding any current information on this, though the caption query string variable seems to have never been documented in the first place.

Does anyone know if this feature is still available under a different query string variable?

To be more clear, I have a link on a web page that attempts to open Instagram in camera mode with a caption.  I have a JavaScript click event that checks after 500ms to see if the page is still open, then alerts the user to download the app if the link didn't work:

```
<a href="instagram://camera?caption=CaptionGoesHere" onclick="tryInstagram(); return false;">Open Instagram</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instagram provides [documentation on iOS hooks](http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/#). That documentation does not make any mention of a caption parameter, except sharing a photo via Obj-C (in which they call it `annotation`). Given the different naming, you could try `instagram://camera?annotation=YourCaptionHere` and it might even work, but this doesn't seem to be an officially-supported use case.

Further, to support your second paragraph, searching through the history of [the docs on the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://instagram.com/developer/) doesn't turn up any mention that `caption` was ever a supported argument... like you said.  Interestingly, one of their co-founders [claimed this was available 2 years ago](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/instagram-api-developers/0lsJyFcfYPw/7bquE0JrpyQJ)... I guess they never made it official, then removed it?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work as a URL coming out of the web browser.  Thanks, though.